# Remotely change resolution settings in xp

Tags: windows-xp, display

In an attempt to get my Boot Camped MBP to work with my flat screen, I idiotically set the display settings to some bizzare resolution and external only. The image flashes on my tv and I can't control it, and it doesn't display at all on my 19" external.

I can boot into VGA mode and I can remote in from my other computer, but I've not found a way to change the display settings so they stick. Even if it's just to change it to 1280X1024 so I can see it on my external I think that would be enough.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Buzkie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that when you booted into VGA mode, you could adjust the resolution and have it keep it after a reboot... Well, what you *could* do is boot into VGA mode, install a VNC server like UltraVNC, then reboot, connect via VNC and adjust how you like it. There's probably a better way, but this would work.

Comment: took a few restarts but it eventually worked. Thanks for the tip